# Problem while trying to retrieve data from checkbox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, checkbox

I am trying to execute the code below to list the select item in a checkbox

to the body of the mail

```
 Dim CheckedValues As String
                For Each item In txt_panview0_ddinput1.Items
                    If item.checked Then
                        checkedValues = checkedValues & item.selectedValue

                    End If
                Next
                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(checkedValues) Then
                    checkedValues = checkedValues.Substring(1)
                End If


                tempCollector = tempCollector + "<br>" + "Area Name" + ": " + checkedValues
```

But i am getting the following error ..

```
System.MissingMemberException: Public member 'checked' on type 'ListItem' not found. 
at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Symbols.Container.GetMembers(String& MemberName, 
Boolean ReportErrors) at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.
LateGet(Object Instance, Type Type, String MemberName, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames, Type[] 
TypeArguments, Boolean[] CopyBack) at WebApplication1._Default.collectEmailBodyText() 
in C:\UseFormCode\UseFormEnhWorking\Default.aspx.vb:line 271
```

Please help

Comment: Can you post the HTML to show what the check boxes are wrapped in?

Comment: What type is txt_panview0_ddinput1 ?

Comment: txt_panview0_ddinput1 is not a listbox it is a checkboxlist –

Comment: Isn't this the code we just converted from C# for you in another question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Typecast each item in the iteration to a `CheckBox` before checking if it's checked:</strike>

```
For Each item In txt_panview0_ddinput1.Items
     dim c as CheckBox = Ctype(item.Value, CheckBox)
     If c.checked Then
         checkedValues = checkedValues & item.selectedValue
    End If
Next
```

To enable selection of multiple values, set the `SelectionMode` property of the `ListBox` to `Multiple` :

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple"></asp:ListBox>
```

Then to iterate over the selected values, use the following:

```
For Each item as ListItem In txt_panview0_ddinput1.Items
         If item.Selected Then
             CheckedValues = CheckedValues & item.Value
        End If
Next
```

*PS I'm a bit rusty on VB.Net syntax so my code may not be syntactically perfect*

Comment: Now its giving :



System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox'. at WebApplication1._Default.collectEmailBodyText() in C:\UseFormCode\UseFormEnhWorking\Default.aspx.vb:line 271

Comment: Try : dim c as CheckBox = Ctype(item.Value, CheckBox)

Comment: Nope still error:


System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox'. at WebApplication1._Default.collectEmailBodyText() in C:\UseFormCode\UseFormEnhWorking\Default.aspx.vb:line 271

Comment: yes its worked but one problem only one selected value is only comming not multiple values :-(

Comment: set the SelectionMode property of the ListBox to Multiple

Comment: there is no such property for my check list box

Comment: txt_panview0_ddinput1 is not a listbox it is a checkboxlist –