# Not retrieving the all selected values from checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, checkbox

Below code is written in such a way to retrieve all selected check box values

But its retieve only the first selected value

Please help

```
Dim CheckedValues As String
                For Each item as ListItem In txt_panview0_ddinput1.Items
                 If item.Selected Then
                     CheckedValues = CheckedValues & item.Value
                End If
                Next
                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(checkedValues) Then
                    checkedValues = checkedValues.Substring(1)
                End If

 tempCollector = tempCollector + "<br>" + "Area Name" + ": " + checkedValues
```

Comment: **DUPE from yourself** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206859/problem-while-trying-to-retrieve-data-from-checkbox

Comment: Please edit your question, instead of posting a new one.

Answer (score 1):

If I read your code correctly, you're mashing together all of the values from your list into a string, without anything separating them.  You therefore have no way of retrieving the original values.

You could try separating your values with a comma before adding them to the string.  But there might be a better way to do this.  It really depends on what you are trying to do.  You might have better luck filling a list object.

Comment: I am trying to put the selected values in a checkbox to tempCollector variable , this tempcollector variable value comes the body of the email

Comment: i couldnt see any property named multiselect for my checkboxlist

Comment: txt_panview0_ddinput1 is not a listbox it is a checkboxlist

Answer (score 0):

Changed CheckedValues = CheckedValues & item.Value

to

CheckedValues += CheckedValues & item.Value perhaps